# How do I set my favicon?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, favicon

How do I set my Favicon in my ASP.Net MVC2 application?

The .ico file is already in the Content folder, now what do I do?

Comment: I just had to add the <link> tag to the <head> of the Master Page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to the  section of your master page(s):

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Content/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />`